# Is href mandatory in anchor element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am not able to display the icon enclosed in `<anchor>` element, if the `href` attribute isn't used in it. It is displayed if I initialize `href` to `""`. ANd also, Even if I manage to display the icon by adding `href=""`, I am not able to change the size of the icon with `width` and `height` attribute. I am trying to add the href attribute using jQuery as I'll have to add some parameters to the URL.

Below is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var content="";
  var quoteContent="";
  var quoteAuthor="";
  $("#click").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("//quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=?", function(key) {
     content=key[0].content + "<p>— " + key[0].title + "</p>";
      quoteContent=key[0].content;
      quoteAuthor=key[0].title;
      $("#quote-form").html(content);
      console.log(content);
    });
    
    $("#quote-form").css({"font-family":"lucida console", "font-size": "20px","color":"rgb(255,255,150)"});
     $("#tweet-prop").attr('href','https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=quotes&related=freecodecamp&text='+encodeURIComponent('"'+quoteContent+'"'+'-'+quoteAuthor));
  });
 
});
```

```css
.position-message{
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right:25%;
  margin-top:5%;
}

div.background{
  background-color: rgba(245,245,245,0.1);
  border-radius:10%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.button-prop{
  /*transformation : translateX(-50%); */
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left : 50%;
   /*-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%); 
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%); 
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%); 
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%); */
}
.quote-shape{
  border-radius: 10%;
 
}

#page{
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-top:2%;
  margin-bottom:2%; 
  width: 1200px;
  height: 450px;
  max-height: 450px;
  
}
#page-background{
  background-image: url(http://www.wallpapers4u.org/wp-content/uploads/grid_background_line_texture_surface_50781_1920x1080.jpg);
  text-align: center;
}

#share {
        
        height:30px;
        width: 80px; 
      }
.space-from-quote{
  padding-top: 2%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700&amp;lang=en" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <Title>Click to get quotes</Title>
</head>

<body id="page-background">
    <div class="well background" id="page">
      
            <div id="quote" class="position-message"> 
             <span><p id="quote-form"></p></span>
            </div>
        <!--<div class="row" id="button-shape">
  <div id="share" class="col">
         <a class="click" href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id={{fbapp_id}}&link={{link_url}}&message={{share_message|urlencode}}&display=popup&redirect_uri={{link_url}}" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i> Share
        </a> 
          </div>-->
      
    </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <a class="button" id="tweet-prop" name="tweet my quote"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <button type="button" id="click" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-circle  button-prop" ><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x"></i>
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I understood why it wasn't displayed. It was because I had added the jQuery inside the `onClick` function. Could someone tell me how to change the size of the icon?

Comment: Are you referring to `#tweet-prop`?

Comment: You can use two options to change the icon size- either use standard Font awesome classes like fa-2x,fa-3x,fa-4x and fa-5x, or else try changing the font size of the icon.

Comment: if it is not a link reference then it's not an anchor element. use a container element like div or span!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's "mandatory" in the sense that you don't really have a hyperlink if it doesn't have an href. If you don't want the link to navigate anywhere, the convention is `href="#"`, with an `e.preventDefault()` at the end of your click handler (which needs an `e` parameter). But an anchor without an href isn't a hyperlink, and so isn't going to be interactive.

If your anchor has a name attribute but not an href attribute, then it's a named anchor. Named anchors aren't meant to be interacted with, and are long obsolete. But more importantly, you seem to be misusing the name attribute completely and not trying to use it for its intended purpose, given that it's `name="tweet my quote"`, which is a nonsensical value for the attribute.